# Write into Excel Destination from SSIS variables

Tags: ssis

I have 3 SSIS variables namely **name, age, gender** with initial values set. I want to write these values into excel sheet in one row. Later I will extend this to Array of records.

To do this I have created **Excel connection** attaching the excel sheet where I want to write.

I added control flow task and double clicked and then added **Derived column** component to create derived columns for each of above 3 variables . Inside derived column editor I selectd above variables as new derived columns.

And then pipelined excel destination component and mapped sheet columns to derived columns. I executed the SSIS package and its successful. But variables are not written into excel sheet.

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is your data source in this Data Flow? Where rows of data are coming from?

Comment: I have no data source component, data is present in SSIS variables

Comment: I believe you need a source component so rows start the flow from there. Derivated column is used to apply transformations or add new columns, but not completely new rows. Once executed, can you see the amount of rows in the link between the derived column and the excel destination? If not, it's 0 rows.

Comment: I added data viewer it does not show up anything, just green ticks

Comment: Added a new answer using script component as your source @EzLo

Answer (score 5):

Again, you need a source. I gave you an "easy" solution. This is probably the best solution to your problem:

This time the source will be a script component (select Source).

Steps after you add Script Component:

1. Select Source
2. Go to Inputs and Outputs
3. Add your Output Columns (Don't forget about data types)

[image: Output Columns Image]

4. Go back to Script
5. Add you variables (Gender, Name and Age)

[image: Image adding variables]

6. Go into Script
7. Add the following code

   ```
   public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
   {
      Output0Buffer.AddRow();
      Output0Buffer.Age = Variables.Age;
      Output0Buffer.Gender = Variables.Gender;
      Output0Buffer.Name = Variables.Name;
   }
   ```

Comment: when puting code after a bullet, you need to ident it twice (dunno why tho). This should be the solution for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need a source. the *easiest* would be to use a SQL connection.

Use a variable of type string named SQL.

```
Set SQL = "Select '" + name+ "' as name,"+ age + "as age,'" + gender + "' as Gender
```

Set your source to SQL variable.

Connect this Source to Destination and you should have 1 row with 3 columns

Comment: you may have to play around with single quotes around strings.

Comment: This works but it's not a good idea to use a connection that you don't really need.

Comment: I didn't feel like going through the effort of doing it in a script task, which is what I would have done.

Comment: I am bored at work and will provide the script component solution

Answer (score 1):

Listing the steps clearly as suggested by **@KeithL**

1. Create a SSIS variable **selectQueryVariables** with **string** datatype.
2. Assign variable expression as

   ```
   "SELECT '"+@[User::name]+"' as Name,'"+@[User::gender]+"' as Gender,"+(DT_WSTR,4 )@[User::age]+" as Age"
   ```
3. Add **OLE DB Source** component and set data access mode as **SQL command from variable** and select the variable **selectQueryVariables** in dropdown. Now the source is ready with 3 columns Name, Age and Gender.
4. Pipeline this with **Excel Destination** and map columns source and destination.